# s3 bucket name when using amazon virtual hosted-style request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Recently I used amazon s3 to build a application.But I found a problem that s3 bucket name could not contain (.) among labels when I used hosted-style request over ssl to download files through browser.For example, a bucket name is 'test.bucket', which contains (.).But it accurs that browser has invalid certificert when I download files using url https://test.bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/filename, the same as posting file to s3 bucket.

After searching the documents, I found the last words in the following url:

[BucketRestriction](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html)

> Additionally, if you want to access a bucket by using a virtual hosted-style request, for example, http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com over SSL, the bucket name cannot include a period (.).

So, I really want to know whether the bucket name could not include a period (.) such as "a.b", "test.bucket" or "abcd.fdf.fdf" exactly.

Comment: Doesn't the quoted Amazon documentation answer your question?

Comment: @DNA I just want to make it sure, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use periods (now) in your S3 bucket names when using SSL. You just have to use the Path Style format. Full explanation [here](http://engineering.aweber.com/amazons-sorta-simple-storage-solution/). Path style looks like this:
https://s3.amazon.aws.com/your.bucket.name